# Jekyll Blog not styled properly in github pages

Tags: css, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have installed jekyll as well as created a post locally. I pushed my commits to the master branch & created an orphan branch gh-pages which has no commits.

In my `_config.yml`, the base url code is this, 
`baseurl: "https://githubusername.github.io/blog"` with blog being my repo.

I added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.scss">` to default.html. 
Whenenver I load this link, https://githubusername.github.io/blog the site doesn't render properly.[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q1p3.png)

What could be my problem/error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set your `baseurl` to just: `/blog`.

   - **Baseurl is the part after** the `url` (`something.github.io`), before the page-path, [read this](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/) for further clarification.
2. Why is your HTML code for stylesheets linking to a `.scss` file? That's SCSS/SASS, which needs to be processed by Jekyll's SASS converter (or your own converter, into a nice CSS file). **HTML only accepts CSS stylesheets**.

   - To do so make sure your SCSS file has a YAML frontmatter, that is 3 dashes (`-`) then 2 newlines, followed by another 3 dashes.
3. Change your stylesheet link in `default.html` to this:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">`

   - Notice the `.css` instead of `.scss`, and also the additional `site.baseurl`

**Alternatively**, should you decide not to deal with all the `site.baseurl`  stuff, you can just have `site.baseurl` remain a value of `"https://githubusername.github.io/blog"` and then just modify the style sheet link to `href= blog/css/main.css` (after converting the `.scss` file) but this defeats the purpose of a baseurl. **Also**, if you decide you don't want it to be in `blog` in the future you'll have to make a ton of link edits.

Comment: I have tried all these but unfruitful. https://githubusername.github.io/blog is loading but not properly so I think its something with the css?

Comment: @matic1088 are you using .css and not .scss? you also need your main.scss to have YAML frontmatter. see this: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/